# Efficiency of panniers vs. Trailer. Weight threshold

Tags: trailer, panniers

Is there a weight where it is more effective to pull a trailer?

Comment: Is the question: If you were going to carry 50 pounds of gear (22.7 Kilograms) would it be more efficient to carry it in paniers or would it be more efficient to use a trailer? Or, are you asking about the weight max of panniers vs trailers?

Answer (score 2):

Panniers have no additional rolling resistance from more wheels, no friction from a hitch, and have a smaller frontal area than a trailer with the same load.

The only downside of panniers is that they add weight to your existing bike so increase rolling resistance from extra weight.

I'd estimate that panniers work better, up to the point they can't hold the load for weight or size reasons, and only then does a trailer become the better/only alternative.

Side note - some loads simply don't work in panniers.  Kids and animals are a poor choice and would require the trailer, or perhaps a handlebar basket for small pets.

Comment: Perfect thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Having transported a child on the bike (seat, not panniers but in terms of weight it's similar, though the balance is worse) and in a trailer towed by the same bike, I'd say keeping the weight on the bike is far preferable if at all possible.  The wheels of a trailer find potholes and debris that your main wheels don't .  It's hard to just barely dodge something with a wheel that's behind you. The effect on handling if the ground is at all rough is far worse.

Also the trailer is more empty weight than panniers, even including pannier racks.  Most also cause more drag as they move through the air (the possible exception being flatbed trailers.

Panniers (and other on-bike luggage) can carry rather a lot:
[image: A rather laden touring bike]

This was my kit for a weekend camping at the beach, and I recall the luggage weighing 35 kg, on a heavy bike (I only rode 2×35km with all that on there).  The highlight is just because I used the photo in [a previous answer about front panniers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/77830/7309).

That said, I do have a trailer, originally for child-carrying currently set up to carry a 24" kid's bike.  That's outgrown now, so I'm going to make a load bed for it so I can carry garden supplies.  The common factor is that the trailer is for things too big to carry on a bike. And (most) bikes do have weight limits